# How to securely store keys in AndroidKeyStore with a password?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, security, keystore

I am trying to create an app which allows users to store their passwords. Now, I allow the users to encrypt their passwords by two ways, first being the biometrics and other being the password

I was able to implement the `biometrics` encryption by creating a secret key in the AndroidKeyStore and setting the `setUsetAuthenticationRequired(true)` when creating the secret key and then authorizing the Cipher with the BiometricsManager.

However, I am not sure, how to implement the password one. I tried looking for `PBE` encrypting but Android docs didn't have much written in it. What is the best solution for this case which is also secure? I would appreciate if there are any links to the same :)

(Note: If I am using PBE encryption, and I am storing the encrypted data (multiple of user's name and password) inside of a RoomDB, how can
I check if the password is correct on the next app run, if there is nothing in the DB  to decrypt and test)

I also found a way that creates a Secret key and then stores the secret key as an entry and uses https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.PasswordProtection to secure the entry. Let me know if this is a secure enough solution or there are even better solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store password in Room, you need to run hash function and then store hash value of your password. Hash is fixed size, no matter how long is your password.

To compare input password with stored in DB you hash your input and compare it with hash stored in database. Because If you apply hash function to the same string, you'll get the same result. If, at least, 1 symbol is wrong - resulting hash will be completely different.

You can check [this one](https://codersee.com/kotlin-pbkdf2-secure-password-hashing/) and use PBKDF2 algorithm. More details on how to choose hash function and what not to use is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-password-hashing)